# How to provide Facebook Meta tags for link to a file?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have the following url to a file on my website:

```
http://www.foo.com/download/1
```

This downloads the file with the force_download function, using the [download helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/download_helper.html).

I've been requested to provide like buttons for these files which are displayed in a html table on one of the site's pages.

So, using [facebook like button tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) I've created the following button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.foo.com/download/1" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

However, because this is a direct link to the file, the correct open graph metadata is not being received e.g. the description is: "%PDF-1.3 %�ãÏÓ 1041 0 obj.."

So **my question** is how do I provide the open graph metadata for links to my downloads? For example:

```
  <meta property="og:type"            content="website" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"             content="http://foo.com/download/1" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"           content="Download 1" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"           content="bar.png" /> 
  <meta property="og:description"     content="File description" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the url that where you download the file itself you can't, since it's (probably) not an html page and even if it is, you wouldn't want to change the content of the file with your own metadata.

What you can try is use some kind of redirection on the URL used by both the clients downloading the file and the crawlers of facebook, and of course you will need an url for the real download too.

On your view sent for like and the users:

```
<!-- meta tags -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://foo.com/download/1" /> 
<!-- .... -->
<body>
    <script>
    // imaginary real download url url
    window.location = '<?php site_url('download/real_download/'.$download_id);?>';
    </script>
</body>
```

Facebook also doesn't seem to understand refresh meta tags, so you can write and avoid javascript usage:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL='<?php site_url('...')?>'">
```

*Disclaimer:* I didn't find any documentation from facebook that describe what their crawlers understand so there's no guarantee that any of these will keep working. I myself using a javascript solution for like a year now in a similar situation.